# Chat superping finds the user, but claims they have no profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message, super-ping

Today I tried to superping some users to spread some positive feelings (summer of love!):

```
@@0001@cs.stackexchange.com, @@0002@cs.stackexchange.com, @@0003@cs.stackexchange.com and @@0004@cs.stackexchange.com, lorem ipsum [...]
```

User IDs anonymised. Chat tells me:

```
[username of 0001] does not have a profile on cs.stackexchange.com
```

The user exists, and the username found is correct. Things I tried, following suggestions of surprised people in TL:

- Replace superping with superping to chat.SE ID -- same error for the next user.
- Drop the commas -- no change

Comment: Maybe they're a ....g-g-g-ghost!!

Comment: Well, I guess I know what I'm looking at tomorrow am...

Comment: What's a super ping?

Comment: @vascogotlost: It's a moderator feature that allows you to @-notify people in chat, no matter what. The normal ping has its limitations.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks, this is the first time I heard of it.

Comment: See this Q&A for more info about what superpings are and how they work: [What is a 'superping'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258040/335251)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue seems to relate to users who haven't been using chat recently, and therefore whose chat account didn't know about their participation on a particular site. Chat now brutally and relentlessly forces a refresh to their chat data when a moderator uses the `@@` trick.

Aka, try again, it should now work.

Comment: Chat should probably just ask nicely, rather than being brutal and relentless.  This *is* the *Summer of Love*, after all =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 ok, in the next build it shall relentlessly love them.

Answer (score 0):

As a mod, I just decided to ping a few users in chat to update them on site design and I had the same problem.
After some fiddling, I worked out I needed to go to their profile -> dashboard -> chat profile and copy the digits from the URL to the superping. After I sent it, their proper usernames showed up in place of the @@[chat id #].
A bit tedious, but it worked.

Comment: You can either superping by typing `@@<chatID>`, or by typing `@<site-userid>@<sitename>.stackexchange.com`. (If you type `@@` and then start typing their username, it'll provide autocomplete suggestions of chat users whose usernames include that text – e.g., starting to type `@@n00` would show a list of chat users whose usernames include that text.) See this Q&A for more info: [What is a 'superping'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258040/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast Hey Blast. No, I tried that. If <chatID> means their chat ID _number_, then yes, but their chat username said no such user (or something similar), and the <site username>@<site> said there wasn't a user by that name on <site>. But when I did what I said above, the just-in-time helper thing found the users. (@@<username> worked on a user that was active in chat, but not on the others (when I say _worked_, I mean the JiT helper found the user)).