# What is a 'superping'?

Tags: support, chat, super-ping

I've seen the word 'superping' be used across SE meta sites.

What does it mean? Is it just a synonym of the word 'ping' (ie. using `@` followed by a user's name to give them a notification in their inbox).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Superpings are a chatroom feature only available to diamond moderators, where they can reach a user *irrespective of past interaction*.

Compare that to a normal ping, where you can `@name` someone in comments or in a chatroom only if they have been active on a post or in that chatroom.

Superpings have a specific format: `@@<chat-id>` or `@@<site-userid>@<sitename>.stackexchange.com` (the latter includes creating a chat account for the user if there isn't one yet); the message is then added to the user inbox with a link to the chatroom.

The chatroom UI for this is quite helpful in that moderators are given just-in-time help when you type `@@`, and it supports searching for users by username and by site profile link. (Note that searching for users by username is [not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327969/users-name-not-being-picked-up-by-superping-suggestion-in-chat) if the user does not have a chat profile.)

Comment: Does this allow moderators to invite new users to chat even though they don't have the required reputation to join it normally?

Comment: @Lilienthal: yes. Moderators can grant access to users < 5 rep to join chat, and superpings work for such users.

Comment: Does this allow moderators to invite users to rooms they would normally be excluded from (moderator only rooms)?

Comment: @anonymous2: rooms can be set to 'private', and moderators can set who has access for any such rooms. This is independent of the superping.

Comment: I thought this explicitly gave low-rep users write access but that's not the case. Only room owners can manually add people [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189276/260382). Low-rep users can see the chat ping notification but can't respond.

Comment: a screenshot would be nice

Comment: Note: I don't think superpings work in multiline messages. (Even if you include `@@<chat-ID>` in your message, or autocomplete/search the username to find their chat ID, the resulting message won't render the target user's chat display name – it'll just look like `@@<chat-id>`, rather than being rendered as `@username` in the displayed message.) Most Markdown/formatting doesn't work in multiline messages either, so this shouldn't come as a surprise, but it's useful to note.